# Using a variable with r.drawable

Tags: android

I'm making a game and want pictures to display behind the obstacles, I'v been using r.drawable... to make pictures, but how I need to change that ... with a variable name

```
picturename = "clouds";

picture = new BitmapFactory().decodeResource(Constants.CURRENT_CONTEXT.getResources(), R.drawable.picturename);
```

I understand it doesn't work like this, but how would I get it to work.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
 String resourceName = "clouds";
 int resourceIdentifier = getResources().getIdentifier(resourceName, "drawable", Constants.CURRENT_CONTEXT.getPackageName());
```

**UPDATE**:

Then

```
picture = new BitmapFactory().decodeResource(Constants.CURRENT_CONTEXT.getResources(), resourceIdentifier);
```

Comment: would I then do 

picture = new BitmapFactory().decodeResource(Constants.CURRENT_CONTEXT.getResources(), R.drawable.resourceIdentifier ); ??

Comment: Updated the answer with usage of identifier

Comment: Okay, but it also says "cannot resolve method getActivity()".  Any idea?

Comment: Well, you can use any `Context` to get package name (updated)